# Add easing to custom animation function

Tags: jquery, scroll, easing

i created a simple function, which animates values based on the current scroll position.

```
function scrollTransition(startValue, endValue, initScroll, distance, scrollTop) {
    var
        min = Math.min,
        max = Math.max,
        sum;

    if(startValue > endValue) {
        sum = min(max((endValue - startValue) / distance * (scrollTop - initScroll) + startValue, endValue), startValue);
    } else {
        sum = min(max((endValue - startValue) / distance * (scrollTop - initScroll) + startValue, startValue), endValue);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

All you have to do is setting a start value and an end value, the initial scroll position, when the transition starts and a distance (in px). So if "initScroll" is 500 and distance is 200, the transition ends at 700px (scrollTop). The "problem" is, that it's just a linear animation. What i am trying to do is adding a fifth parameter ("easing") to the function, like you do in the jQuery .animation() function.

These are the easing functions i am talking about (https://github.com/danro/jquery-easing/blob/master/jquery.easing.js), but i am not sure, how to add them to this function, so i can use something like

```
// in window scroll function
$el.css({
     "margin-top" : scrollTransition(-300, 500, 500, 1000, "easeOutBack")
});
```

Is something like this possible at all or do i have to stick to a linear transition?

Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### **Update:**

Well, it took me some time but I think I got it. Because you made your own 'custom' function, it was a bit harder to accomplish.

### The Intuition

To explain everything I did, let's start with the absolute basis of linear formulas.

- Let's say we can visualise your custom function as a linear function `f(x)=x`
- Let's say we can visualise the easing functions as a nonlinear function. For example let's say we consider the function `g(x)=sin(x)` as our easing function (this corresponds to the easing method `easeInSine`)

Let's consider these functions in a two dimensional plot:

[image: plot of linear and nonlinear function]

As you can see, I have now drawn two different functions. If we would visualise these functions as our functions in JavaScript, then they are two seperate functions we can call independently. For example:

```
function linear(x)
{
   return x;
}

function sin(x)
{
   return Math.sin(x);
}
```

Now we can use both these functions as a scrollTransition but that's not what we want.

You asked the specific question: *How to add the nonlinear function to my custom linear function?*

So let's consider some of the possibilities we have with our two functions:

1. we can add them together
2. we can substract them
3. we can do nothing
4. we can take the average
5. etc...

Let's visualise the first point:

[image]

The grey lines indicate the original functions and the blue line are the functions added together.

For the second point we would get:

[image]

Where again, the grey lines indicate the original functions and the blue line are the functions added together. (well... in this case: '*subtracted* from each other')

### The Code

Let's consider everything we know:

- We know that your function gives back a certain *linear-determined* value
- We know that the easing functions give back a certain *nonlinear-determined* value

So just like with the graphs, we can add and substract these values to add the functions together.

To accomplish this with your function, I added two parameters to your function:

- `easingEffect` which should be the name of the nonlinear easing effect you want to add (or substract) from your custom function
- `plus` which can take on values `-1`, `0` and `1` and which will determine *how* the nonlinear effect is handled:

  - `-1` the nonlinear function will be substracted from your custom linear function
  - `0`  the nonlinear function will not be used
  - `1`  the nonlinear function will be added to your custom linear function

An example of this would be:

```
$(".element").css({
    "opacity": 1-scrollTransition(0, 1, 0, 400, scrollTop, "easeInSine", 1),
    "left": scrollTransition(0, 200, 0, 300, scrollTop, "easeOutBounce", 1)
});
```

Then what I did within your function basically comes down to the following:

```
sum += plus*easingEffect(null, scrollTop, startValue, endValue, distance);
```

Where the easing effect is determined by the [easing js](https://github.com/danro/jquery-easing/blob/master/jquery.easing.js) you supplied yourself.

Unfortunately, I ended up doing a lot of manual work because for your custom function we need the easing functions to return values *without* having to call the `jQuery.animate()` function. But you don't have to worry about that anymore: I did all the work already so you can now just sitback and play around with the settings to see what happens.

You can find the (fully implementable) solution here: [the code at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5pYMh/2/).

You can do some cool things like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3rUU6/).

### Details for Implementation

Beware of the following things:

For `opacity`, adding two values together is quite dangerous because the CSS property will give an error if you're trying to pass an argument that's bigger than `1`. Therefore I do the following:

```
 "opacity": 1-scrollTransition(0, 1, 0, 400, scrollTop, "easeInSine", 1),
```

So I basically reverse the function (I let the function 'work' from 0 to 1 instead of from 1 to 0) and then I do `1-'the function'` to make sure the values are never above 1. Note that this should be coherent with substracting or adding the nonlinear function.

Also, if you scroll down in the javascript, you will see all the functions and the huge switch statement: you must add all of these to your final javascript file.

So what I suggest is that you just copy the whole javascript section to your own project.

Furthermore, the jsFiddle should be self-explanatory.

Good luck and I hope I answered your question!

### UPDATE 2

`demrks` did the following:

```
sum = easeOutBounce(null, sum, startValue, endValue, distance);
```

To gain more intuition about adding the parameter `sum` to the easing functions, consider the following graph:

[image]

Where the blue line indicates the outcome of your function.

So what your are basically doing is called a `linear transformation` of the easing function or `linear mapping` the easing function. You can read more about this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map).

But what it basically comes down to is that you are changing 'the form' of the easing function by the following properties:

- How fast the easing animation 'goes'
- When it starts/ terminates

So if that is what you want to accomplish, then its perfectly fine and you can use it outside of jsFiddle as well. To me it seems a bit messy, though, because you lose control over the exact animation of the whole (the joint function) since you added an extra level of complexity to the parameters. Or in other words: the programming becomes harder because you don't know exactly what the outcome will be.

I hope that answers your last point of interest as well :)

Happy programming!

### UPDATE 3

`demrks` asked why the easing functions have limitations on their parameters.

Let's consider such a `easing` function:

```
function easeOutBounce(x, t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t/=d) < (1/2.75)) {
        return c*(7.5625*t*t) + b;
    } else if (t < (2/2.75)) {
        return c*(7.5625*(t-=(1.5/2.75))*t + .75) + b;
    } else if (t < (2.5/2.75)) {
        return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.25/2.75))*t + .9375) + b;
    } else {
        return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.625/2.75))*t + .984375) + b;
    }
}

//x = null;
//t = currentTime;
//b = begin;
//c = end;
//d = distance;
```

Simply by looking at the function we come to the following conclusions:

- If `c=0`, then the function will return the value `b`

  - If `b<0` and `c=0`, then the function will return the negative value `b`
- If `c<0`, then the function will return a negative value

Note that we have defined opacity as:

```
"opacity": 1-scrollTransition(0, 1, 0, 400, scrollTop, "easeInSine", 1)
```

Hence if the function `scrollTransition(0, 1, 0, 400, scrollTop, "easeInSine", 1)` returns a negative value, we will have an error in the `$(".element").css(...);` property and so nothing will happen.

So basically the easing functions work fine. Just if you apply them to the property opacity we sometimes have the constraint:

- `endValue > 0`

Talking about the behaviour of functions, let's consider another one:

```
 function easeInOutElastic(x, t, b, c, d) {
    var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
    if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d/2)==2) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*(.3*1.5);
    if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
    else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
    if (t < 1) return -.5*(a*Math.pow(2,10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )) + b;
    return a*Math.pow(2,-10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )*.5 + c + b;
}
```

Note that for this one, the function is highly dependent on the variable `d` (distance).

Hence, the formulas work fine.

It's just that you have to be careful for *how* you apply them and *how* they behave that might make things complicated.

### What's wrong  with jsFiddle

Regarding working in jsFiddle, be very careful of how you initialise your document.

For example I found that animating from `-300` to `200` with easing works fine **IF** you put the `document width` larger than the **animation space** (space that the animation needs to execute properly).

You can see a working code of animating from `-300` to `200` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5pYMh/4/).

Note that I changed the document width:

```
body {
    height: 2000px;
    width: 800px;
}
```

That should answer your question. Good luck!

### Update 4

To shorten the `switch statement`, you can also use:

```
var call = eval(easingEffect);
sum += call(null, scrollTop, startValue, endValue, distance);
```

As you can see in [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/wvX2e/1/) example. That might save you some manual work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that i already know, how to use easing with jQuery animate() function. For my animation i'm not using animate() or anything similar like fadeIn(), fadeOut, but i am using my custom function to animate elements depending on the scroll position. You can see my custom function above, i called it "scrollTransition". At the moment this is a linear transition, but i want it to be eased with either the jQuery easing (fifth parameter as described) or at least with some kind of easing. But i am not really good at maths, so i don't know how to add easing to it.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! It makes your question more understandable. You don't have to be good in maths to accomplish this. I will try to help you this evening.

Comment: Thank you, but hasn't easing to do with maths? We could somehow make use of the jQuery easing functions (link in first post), so i don't have to be good in maths, but i'm not sure how to integrate them into my function.

Comment: @demrks: Check my updated response above. Please answer my questions so I can answer yours.

Comment: @demrks, Please update my jsFiddle such that your function works as it should and then post the link here together with explanation of what you want to do with the return value.

Comment: Thanks again, i should have explained this in the first post obviously. Sorry... To answer your questions i created a quick and dirty fiddle with an example usage for this function (Just scroll down and the <div> should fadeOut and move to the right while scrolling): http://jsfiddle.net/EhPMF/embedded/result/
The explanation of the parameters:
1.) "startValue" and "endValue": If i want to animate the opacity from 0 to 1 (fadeIn) the "startValue" is 0 and the "endValue" is 1 (see fiddle)

Comment: 2.) "initScroll" is not the current scroll position, but the scroll position, where the animation should start. So if it has a value of "300" the animation starts as soon as you scrolled more then 300px from top.
3.) "scrollTop" is not a parameter, because it is always the current scroll position ($window.scrollTop())

To see what the "sum" value is used for, have a look at the fiddle. I hope that makes sense to you.

Comment: I am sorry, i red your answer too late, because i was writing all the time. I updated your fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/C9ZJ8/2/

Comment: @demrks: I think I got it. Check the (huge) answer above.

Comment: If i could, i would upvote your answer at least 10 more times!! Thank you so much, that was exactly what i was looking for. Even with my bad math skills, i understood the way it was done :) You should think of becoming a teacher or something. I'm not sure if this could work as well, but i updated your fiddle with some minor changes http://jsfiddle.net/5pYMh/3
Instead of adding the easing to the linear function (as you described) i used "sum" as a parameter for the easing functions. Probably my changes won't work for animations other than what i did in the fiddle, have to test it :)

Comment: @demrks: Thank you for your enthusiasm; it's the perfect reward for the work I put in. And thank you for your compliment, I'm not thinking of becoming a teacher but maybe when I'm old and bored I should consider it haha. To answer your last point of interest: check the new update above. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that fully answers my last point as well and you are right that my edit to the fiddle probably made it harder to guess the outcome of this whole function. I can now start implementing your easing in my final project :) Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but i just realized (while implementing your code) that negative start or end values don't work. So if the start value is -200 and it should animate to 300 (endValue) the "sum" is kind of strange. If the endValue is 0 it doesn't animate at all. I tried with both with my change and without. Probably this can't be fixed, but maybe you have an idea why it only works if both values are positive and the startValue < endValue? Strange thing: without easing it works :)

Comment: Actually that's not strange at all: your function is just better than the easing functions concering this. I will make a small update to show you why.

Comment: Thanks, i just realized that it works with negative values as well, but the start value needs to be smaller than the end value. If i want to animate from 300 to -200 it doesnt work. Fiddle doesn't work for me right now (server down?), so i can't show you my example code :(

Comment: @demrks: It's up again. Yes exactly. Wait let me show you for both cases.

Comment: Thanks once again for your time! Now everything should work out for me and i have a proper function to work with this and upcoming (similar) projects :)

Comment: @demrks: I made my code a bit more concise. Check update. I wanted to call the function with `var myFunc = window[myFuncName];` but only `eval` seemed to work in jsFiddle. Anyway, the switch statement is gone now.

Comment: Thanks again, actually i looked up the same thing to get rid of the switch statement one or two days ago. Evil is one solution, which i found, but "eval" is "evil" (at least as far as i heard :)). So i came up with this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/wvX2e/2/
This way you can just include the easing file and don't have to rewrite it. So you can use it for both this scroll transition an jQuery animate() for example.

Comment: I am not sure if long conversations like that are allowed in this comments section.. but in the updated fiddle above you can see that it is using: "scrollTransition(0, 200, 0, 300...)". So what it should do is animate the value from 0px to 200px starting at 0px "scrollTop" and ending the animation as soon as you scrolled more than 300px. In the updated fiddle you should see the values inside the black box. In my current project it wasn't too important, but in the fiddle you can see that the values of the function (see above) doesn't fit the actual values pixel perfect (ScrollTop:100>Value:234)

Comment: @demrks: I tried to make it work without `eval` as well (like I said in the comment) but couldn't succeed. But if it worked for you then that's indeed a better solution. And by having the functions there seperately, you can use them for anything except for just `animate` as we can then call them independently. So I consider that to be even better. Unfortunately, your jsFiddle doesn't work for me...

Comment: By accident i came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/wvX2e/3/ , which is basicly just the easing function, which seems to work pixel perfect in the fiddle (ScrollTop:300>Value:200). But then i found out that this one is completely ignoring the "initScroll" and always starts at 0px scrollTop. This would have been to easy :)

Comment: Does this code pen work for you instead to see the solution without eval? http://cdpn.io/pghdl

Comment: I just saw the comments (didn't get any notification about them). But both the jsFiddle and the pen don't work for me (Google Chrome version 28.0.1500.72 m)